# Sum From Lookup SSRS Reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, lookup

If i take a 4 day period it only shows capacity from the latest day, but I need to show the total capacity over 4 days. I try to sum the capacity wich is a lookup that looks like this:

```
=Lookup(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!Name.Value,Fields!capacity.Value, "table_1")
```

It does not work if I just add a `Sum()` in the beginning and I've tried to solve it with `Code.Lookup_Sum` but `lookup_Sum` gets red.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: want]

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to add a column group for your capacity field based on a week or another time frame and set the aggregate value as that column stretches outward.

Comment: The Capacity field is just a expression, how can i add a column group on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count Capacity in the QUERY as total Capacity